# Check there there exists only one null in each row, between two columns MySql (version 8.0.13)

Tags: mysql, sql, testing, count, null

I have two columns `col1` and `col2` under table name `table`. Ideally, the data in the table should look like:

```
 col1 | col2
  A     null
  null   B
  null   A
  C      null
```

The data would have an error if there exists a row in which both columns are `null` or if both columns have a value. So for example if there is a row that looks like

```
 col1| col2
  A     B
```

or

```
col1 | col2
 null   null
```

I can count the number of nulls in each column by using a query like 
    `select count(*) from table where col1 IS NULL`
    `select count(*) from table where col2 IS NULL`

However, just knowing the counts of the `null`s and adding them up does not tell me where the `null`s actually exist in the table. Is there a query that I can write to test if there exists only one null in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find count of rows with error, you can use `AND` condition to check if **both** the columns are `null` simultaneously, or **are not null** simultaneously:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows_with_error
FROM your_table 
WHERE (col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL) OR 
      (col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  You can get the count of correct rows using:

```
select sum( (col1 is null and col2 is not null) or
            (col1 is not null and col2 is null)
          ) as one_null_per_row
from t;
```

Or:

```
select count(*)
from t
where (col1 is null and col2 is not null) or
      (col1 is not null and col2 is null);
```

(The first version lets you add other summaries.)

You can get the rows with errors using:

```
select t.*
from t
where (col1 is null and col2 is null) or
      (col1 is not null and col2 is not null)
```